# How memory leak occupies memory more than JVM allocated

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am facing a problem at my Ubuntu machine that got slow after 4-5 hours usage, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019145/ubuntu-lts-16-04-memory-usage-rises-as-lag-increases) is the link of my question.

In the comments section, experts suggested some memory leak in my Java application on which I was working, so as a learner this question arises to my mind that in case my java application causing a memory leak, so JVM has been assigned a certain amount of memory (i.e. process memory) and any memory leak can causes that much memory to be occupied and then it has to show `OutOfMemoryException`, but why and how it consumes all memory (i.e. greater than process memory) but not giving OOM exception?

```
~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: which version of the JVM are you using? That will greatly impact the answer given.

Comment: @StevenFines sir updated the answer and also got a little hint , as java 8 has got changes in memory management , are you also referring to that change?

Comment: Yes, the 1.8 JVM contains changes to allow for off-heap memory which is how you can see the JVM using more memory than specifically allocated in the heap argument (-Xmx)

Comment: @StevenFines sir you are great , why i didnt get that at my own